# C++ Multithreading Error : no matching function for call to 'std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>

Tags: c++, multithreading, compiler-errors, cygwin, brute-force

The console gives the below error :

```
brute.cpp: In function 'void createThreads(int, int, MAP&, std::string)':
../brute.cpp:125:67: error: no matching function for call to 'std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>, std::reference_wrapper<std::unordered_map<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >, std::string&)'
  125 |     threadVec.push_back(std::thread(remove, std::ref(bufObj), hash));
```

```
/***************** Method to check if the current buffer has a match of the given hash ***********/
void remove(MAP &buffer, std::string hash) {
        while (buffer.size() > 0)
        {
            const auto itrHash = buffer.find(hash);
            if (itrHash == buffer.end()) {
                buffer.erase(itrHash, buffer.end());
            }
            else {
                std::cout.flush();
                std::cout << "\t*********\n\t SUCCESS :: The Password of the Hash to Check is " << itrHash->first << " is " << itrHash->second;
                cracked = true;
            }
        }
        return;
    }

/***** Method to accumulate a hash and the respective string value to a unordered set of <string, string>
***********************/
void accumulate_hash(MAP &buffer, int beginIndex, int endIndex, int wordLen){

    while (beginIndex < endIndex) {
        std::cout << charList[beginIndex] <<'\n';
        std::string prefix(1,charList[beginIndex]);
        std::cout << prefix << '\n';
        printAllKLengthRec(charList, prefix, sizeofArr, wordLen - 1, buffer);
        beginIndex++;
    }
}

/*@brief The method that equally divides the work between threads
* @params wordLen The length of the word
* @params threadCount Based on number of Cores
* @buffObj That stores all the hashs and the respective values
* @&threads Reference to list of Threads
**/
void createThreads(int wordLen, int threadCount, MAP &bufObj, std::string hash) {

    int  index = 0;
    int charListSize = std::strlen(charList);
    int charSetSize = charListSize / threadCount;
    int difference = charListSize % threadCount;
    int equallydividedWork = charSetSize;
    std::vector<std::thread> threadVec;
    std::cout<< hash << '\n\n';

/*******************Below Line is where the error is generated ********************/

    threadVec.push_back(std::thread(remove, std::ref(bufObj), hash));

/*********************** ---------------------------------- **********************/
   
 // The character list is divided into equal set of characters
 // Each character Set is then used to generate strings that creates hashes

    int i = 0;
    while (index < charListSize) {
        if (charSetSize == 0)
            charSetSize = 1;
        if(i + 1 == threadCount)
            charSetSize += difference;

/***************Compiler Does not have issue with the below line though *********************/

        // Threads are created

        threadVec.push_back(std::thread(accumulate_hash, std::ref(bufObj), index, charSetSize, wordLen));

/********************* ---------------------------------------------------**********/


        index = charSetSize;
        charSetSize = charSetSize + equallydividedWork;
        if (charSetSize >= charListSize) {
            charSetSize = charListSize;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Just guessing, maybe the function name `remove` is clashing with [`std::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove) from `<cstdio>`? Try naming your function differently and see if it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like this:

```
std::thread tmpThread{ remove, std::ref(bufObj), hash };
threadVec.push_back(std::move(tmpThread));
```

I assume the error is about the missing copy constructor. Thread's can only be moved.

I would use the standard function async: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/async/ instead of spawning threads directly as it matches your use case more do just to do something async once and not repeatedly.

Comment: Changed my method name remove to crack_the_hash; used your recommendation, but now I am getting error that is stated below std::future<bool> fut = std::async(crack_the_hash, buffer, hash); no matching function for call to 'async(bool (&)(MAP&, std::string), MAP*, std::string&)